# Mail script not functioning

Tags: php, email

I've been struggling with this the entire day. The server used to work without smtp authentication. Now it doesn't anymore.
So I created a mail adress to forward the filled in scripts to my email adress.
I used to get errors. Now I'm not getting any errors anymore, but I'm still not getting the any mail.

Maybe you guys can see if there is something wrong with my code.

```
require_once "Mail.php";
$recipient = "mwmhermans@outlook.com"; //Het email adres van de persoon die vragen moet ontvangen. 
$subject = "Dealership request." + $_POST['naam']; //Subject van de mail. 
$header = "From: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n"; 
$mail_body = "Contact script was executed on " . date("d-m-Y") . " at " . date("H:i") . " \n";  // tijd van uitvoering
$mail_body .= "The following person executed the script:\n\n";
$mail_body .= "Name: " . $_POST['naam'] . "\n"; 
$mail_body .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n";
$mail_body .= "Company: " . $_POST['company'] . "\n"; 

$host = "";
$username = "";
$password="";

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($recipient, $subject, $header, $body);

echo '<div style="margin-left:25px;"><div class="wrapper">';
echo "<br/><b>Your request is successfully sent.</b><br>You'll get a response as soon as possible.</b><br>"; 
echo "<a class=\"main\" href='javascript:history.back(1)'>Back</a>";
echo '</div></div>';
```

Comment: What's in the logs? does your class return any errors? How is this class, which you use, is named (name of the library)?

Comment: Have you checked spam folders?

Comment: I do believe headers need to be the last entry. Try `$mail = $smtp->send($recipient, $subject, $body, $header);`

Comment: I checked the logs no errors at all

Comment: doesnt show up in spam folders.
@Fred-ii-
tried it didn't work unfortunatly

Comment: @TheUnknown This line doesn't seem right with the `+` sign `$subject = "Dealership request." + $_POST['naam'];` I think what you're trying to do is concatenate the subject with the person's name. Try `$subject = "Dealership request" . $_POST['naam'];` or `$subject = "Dealership request" . $_POST['naam'] . "\r\n";`

Comment: `if (PEAR::isError($mail)) { echo $mail->getMessage(); }`

Comment: tried changing that too no still no email though.

Comment: @SamuelCook thanks now I know that i need to make the header a array

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are setting incorrect parameters to `send` function. As [manual page](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php) says, the synopsis is:

```
mixed send ( mixed $recipients , array $headers , string $body )
```

While you are calling it like this:

```
send(mixed $recipient, string $subject, string $header, string $body);
```

Please, look at the example on that page and change your code according to it.

Comment: atleast it is sending me a mail now. but its sending me a failure notice

Comment: @TheUnknown Please, explain, what a failure notice is, how it is generated? Try to debug yourself too.

Comment: I used the debug again nothing comes up, it seems to be a server problem

this is what i get in my mailbox
http://skyhighcaraudio.net/Knipsel.PNG

Comment: figured out that I messed up on the From

Comment: @TheUnknown Great. Glad, that you did it.

Comment: Today I tried to change the php version to php 5.4 since it was still at 5.2 but after I did that the mail function didn't work anymore. Any idea how this could be.

Comment: @TheUnknown Did you put the headers into array and did everything according to manual? Any errors?

Comment: just was about to come back and say that I found a error after debugging. I made a typo and apperantly that wasn't a problem in 5.2 but it was in 5.4